# Using the content-range header as the collectionSize for NgbPagination in a Table

Tags: angular, html-table, pagination, http-headers, ng-bootstrap

I have implemented a table with pagination based on the Pagination example for the Table component in the ng-bootstrap library (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples).

In the `<ngb-pagination>` element, I define my `collectionSize` like the following:

```
[collectionSize]="collectionSize || async"
```

This works fine, but this way I have to make an endpoint in my API specifically for the count of items. It would be a lot easier if I could just use the value from a `Content-Range` header which is being sent while retrieving the items in the table.

I implemented the table and the pagination like this:

**HTML**

```
    <tbody *ngIf="items | async as rcvItems">
      <tr *ngFor="let item of rcvItems">
        <th scope="col">{{ item.x }}</th>
        <td scope="col">{{ item.y }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

...

    <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="collectionSize | async" [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="pageSize" [maxSize]="5"
          [rotate]="true" [ellipses]="false">
    </ngb-pagination>
```

**TS**

```
ngOnInit(){
  // count() gets the total amount of items
  this.collectionSize = this.service.count();
  // list() gets all the items
  this.items = this.service.list(this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize);
}
```

**Service TS**

```
list(limit, offset): Observable<Item[]> {
  return this.http
    .get(this.baseUrl + '?limit=' + limit + '&offset=' + offset)
    .pipe(
      map((data: any[]) =>
        data.map(item => this.itemAdapter.adapt(item))
      )
    );
}
```

I tried to get the headers in the `list()` method by adding `tap(response => response.headers.get('Content-Range')),`, but that didn't seem to work.
Would it be possible to somehow get the headers for the responses of the received items of the `list()` method, and use those as the collectionSize?

Thanks.